# Recurring probability

Tags: probability

I'm trying to calculate some probabilities to simulate a small game and struggling with a recurring event formula.

I have an object who is a character, this character has 5 lives. The character repeatedly gets hit by an enemy and every time he gets hit, there is a 76% chance he will lose a life.

How can I figure out based on this, how many hits on average a character will live for?

I can simulate this in a spreadsheet but was hoping to get a more accurate formula so I could calculate it for any % chance easily.

My understanding of probability is limited, and I'm hoping to implement this formula in a spreadsheet once I figure it out.

Comment: when you ask how long the character will live, is that for 1 life or all 5?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how many events the character will live for in total for all 5 lives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that in theory an object can survive any finite number of hits, although with small probability. Let $p = 1 - 0.76 = 0.24$ and let $N$ be the number of hits the object survives. Then,
$$
\mathbb{P}[N=0] = 1-p \\
\mathbb{P}[N=1] = p (1-p) \\
\mathbb{P}[N=2] = p^2 (1-p) \\
\ldots \\
\mathbb{P}[N=k] = p^k (1-p) \\
$$
Thus, $N$ is a [geometrically distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) random variable with possible values $\{0,1,\ldots\}$. Now then in process of one life your character is expected to survive
$$
\mathbb{E}[N] = \frac{1-p}{p} = \frac{0.76}{0.24} = 3.16\bar{6} \text{ hits}.
$$

So over $5$ lives, you would survive $5\mathbb{E}[N] = 15.83\bar{3}$ hits.

Comment: I apologize, while you may be correct I don't understand probability formulas well enough to implement it myself to confirm. Are you able to give me an example using p = 0.24 to calculate the average number of hits the character will survive using your formula above?

Comment: @Alex.Ritna updating now, one sec

Comment: You just need the last formula: p/(1-p). Plug in p=.24

Comment: @Alex.Ritna all done, please see the update

Comment: @gt6989b That was perfect thank you!